# PHP: check if file exists on AWS Lightsail server

Tags: php, file-exists

I'm using the following code to test if an image exists on my server. I'm on a AWS Lightsail server.

I've tried all methods, but none work. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? I've tested the URL in $imgFullURL (copy/paste into browser)and the image is on the server.

**Method One** - Uses the full URL to the image.

```
$imgFullURL = "http://mywebsiteDotCom/images/fileName.jpg";

    if (file_exists($imgFullURL)) {
        echo "The file $imgFullURL EXISTS";
    } else {
        echo "The file $imgFullURL does NOT exist";
    }
```

**Method Two** - Uses the full server path to the image.

```
$imgPathFull = "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/images/fileName.jpg";

    if (file_exists($imgPathFull)) {
        echo "The file $imgPathFull EXISTS";
    } else {
        echo "The file $imgPathFull does NOT exist";
    }
```

**Method Three** - Uses root relative path to the image.

```
$imgPathRoot = "/images/fileName.jpg";

    if (file_exists($imgPathRoot)) {
        echo "The file $imgPathRoot EXISTS";
    } else {
        echo "The file $imgPathRoot does NOT exist";
    }
```

Comment: Show `ls -la /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/images/fileName.jpg` (run it in the ssh terminal)

Comment: @zerkms -rw-rw-r-- 1 bitnami bitnami 39474

Comment: What user you run that script under?

Comment: @zerkms to be honest, I'm not sure. I'm not a developer, just a weekend warrior. This is my 1st time using an AWS system. The code works on a standard shared or managed server, but for some reason it isn't working on this set up. How do I check the 'user' I'm using?

Comment: There is nothing AWS-specific here, it's just another linux server. Check what user those scripts run under and check whether every directory in the path has both `r` and `x` for that user. "How do I check the 'user' I'm using?" --- it all depends on how you configured php sapi.